# While/Switch in php

Tags: php, while-loop, switch-statement

I've been trying to teach myself php and I came across this code (as with all code I try it out myself to get a better understanding etc) but this one doesn't run.

```
<?php 
$i = 0; 
while($i++){
 switch ($i) { 
 case 5: 
 echo "At 5<br />"; 
 break 1; 
 case 10: 
 echo "At 10; quitting<br />"; 
 break 2; 
 default: 
 break; 
 } 
}
 ?>
```

The output is just blank but would i be correct in saying that $i is incremented until it hits 5, at which point switch($i) would go to case 5 at echo "At 5" and then it'll break that switch statement and continue in the while loop incrementing $i till it reaches 10, then it'll repeat the same process and go to echo "At 10; quitting" and the break 2 would leave the switch and while loop?

During all the other values for $i i'm assuming it goes to default and just breaks out of the switch

Thank You.

Comment: in the first loop $i value is goes to default and it breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
$i = 0; 
while($i++){
```

When you do `$i++` the variable `$i` is incremented with one but the value that is returned is still the old value, see the manual on [Incrementing/Decrementing operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php). So the first time when `$i` is still `0`, the condition evaluates to `false` and the whole `while()` loop is never run / your `switch` is never reached.

To increase first and then return the value, you do:

```
$i = 0; 
while(++$i){
```

See the [example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Vs3ang).

Comment: Ahhhhh, this makes sense, thank you! explained it well

Answer (score 0):

Try and make your code more readable by using variables/constants instead of magic numbers and you can also use labels on loops to break/continue on. Here is an example for you:

```
define("SOMETHING", 5);
define("SOMETHING_ELSE", 10);

$count = 0;

mainLoop:
while($count < 100) { #loop virtually forever

  switch(++$count) { #increment and switch on $count in each iteration

      case SOMETHING: #$count = 5
          #do something here
          echo "At 5<br />";
          break; #break switch, continue while loop

      case SOMETHING_ELSE: #$count = 10
          #do something else here 
          echo "At 10; quitting<br />";
          break mainLoop; #break while loop

  }

}
```